# AirPods no longer connect to my Mac

Tags: macos, high-sierra, bluetooth, airpods

I have a Mid-2012 15" Retina Macbook Pro running 10.13.5 which I have been using my AirPods with successfully since I got them over a year ago.

For some reason, today, when I try to connect them, nothing happens.  I've tried rebooting.  Un-pairing and re-pairing them.  They still work with my iPhone.

I noticed this in the Console when I try to connect:

```
default 14:21:52.245048 -0600   bluetoothd  ***** Temporarily stopping all scans *****
default 14:21:52.331071 -0600   SystemUIServer  [openConnection] self=0x6080002e3c00 EXPANSION.authenticationRequired=0
default 14:21:52.331518 -0600   SystemUIServer  [openConnection] self=0x6080002e3c00 target=0x60c000279ec0 return=0x00000000
default 14:22:02.659245 -0600   bluetoothd  Create connection failed (0x4) for device: 7C-04-D0-A6-1D-CB
default 14:22:02.659318 -0600   bluetoothd  DaemonHCIEventNotificationHandler_ConnectionComplete - 04
default 14:22:02.661284 -0600   SystemUIServer  Failed to connect to the device: 0x4
default 14:22:04.246890 -0600   bluetoothd  ***** Starting after temporarily stopping all scans *****
```

Is there some other place I can look to see what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having stumbled upon [this article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/bradmoon/2017/07/13/this-trick-may-solve-your-mac-bluetooth-connectivity-issues/#1485bbc25196), I tried unchecking "Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices" and that seemed to work.  Even when I checked it back on the connection seems to be holding.  I fail to see what Handoff has to do with Bluetooth but at least it works, for now.

Comment: Did you do anything else before changing that setting? I've got the same problem and tried unchecking "allow handoff", but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Wow, I actually can confirm that after disabling Handoff I could get it to connect. Then I re enabled it. :shrug:

Comment: WOW, I had my nerves on the verge of cracking and then this worked. Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything that has been suggested, but did not work. **So I've logged-out of iCloud and tried connecting again, it worked**. Just in case if it makes any difference I have the "Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices" UNCHECKED in General Preferences (as suggested by Darrell Brogdon [above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328780/331705).).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed AirPod pairing by

- Turning Bluetooth off
- Delete all Bluetooth preference files in `/Library/Preferences`, `/System/Library/Preferences`, `~/Library/Preferences`
- Restart mac
- "Forget" Airpods from iPhone. This removes it from iCloud
- Reset Airpods by holding button until amber light flashes

Only then was I able to connect from my laptop to my Airpods.